# jQuery loop calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bring some records using php and do some calculations. What i am doing now is that, each row is having a dropdown with different currencies. When i select each currency, it calculates and shows certain values. Till here its working fine.

What i am trying to achieve is that if i select first currency dropdown, it should calculate the complete records calculations instead of selecting the currency of each rows. I guess i need to do some kind of loop in the jquery which calculates the rows.

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btpxq5ow/3/)

Fiddle u can see the code, but not getting the output properly. so i just put the code in a server also. Link is http://spreadon.net/quot.html

Following is the part of jquery script for the currency dropdown.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").on('change', function() {

      var dept_number = $(this).val();
      var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
      var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

      if (selected == "INR") {
        $(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val($(this).closest('table').find('.total').val());
      } else {
        $(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val((($(this).closest('table').find('.total').val() * price) / $(this).closest('table').find('.inrvalue').val()).toFixed(3));
      }

      $(this).closest('table').find('.price_unit').val(($(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val() / $(this).closest('table').find('.qty').val()).toFixed(3));

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: you can iterate the row. using $.each("tr",function(e){}) which will iterate thought all row of table

Comment: so i just need to change     $("select").on('change', function() { with....$.each("tr",function(e){..??

Comment: iam new to jquery, so can u pls guide me on this?

Comment: Your help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I have added working code which will guide you how to iterate through tr and it td on change of select

see the code it will give you hint about it.

and you have a power of this in each method usind this you can achive your goal.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("select").on('change', function() {

     var dept_number = $(this).val();
     var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');

     var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

     if (selected == "INR") {
       $(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val($(this).closest('table').find('.total').val());

     } else {

       $(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val((($(this).closest('table').find('.total').val() * price) / $(this).closest('table').find('.inrvalue').val()).toFixed(3));
     }

     $(this).closest('table').find('.price_unit').val(($(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val() / $(this).closest('table').find('.qty').val()).toFixed(3));


     // this is upto your logic.

     //now i have write my code which will ittrate through each row and column

     $(".trToiitrate").each(function(e) {
       alert("it is from tr");
       $(this).find("td").each(function(e) {
         alert("this is from td");
       });
     });

   });




 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name='cart' method='post' class='single' action='generate_quot_cust_edititems_save_complete.php?tender_id=151399'>
  <input size='1' type='hidden' name='id[3]' value='1582' readonly/>
  <input type='hidden' name='sum_input' id='sum_input' value=''>
  <div align="center">
    <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
          <th width=6%>SlNo</th>
          <th width=15%>Description</th>
          <th width=5%>Qty</th>
          <th width=5%>Unit Price</th>
          <th width=5%>Total</th>
          <th width=8%>Total (INR)</th>
          <th width=7%>Total Value</th>
          <th width=7%>Currency</th>
          <th width=7%>Total</th>
          <th width=7%>Price/Unit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div align="center" class="base">
    <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tbody id="people">
        <tr class="trToiitrate">
          <td width='6%'>
            <input size='1' type='hidden' name='id[0]' value='1579' readonly/>
            <input size='1' type='text' name='sl[0]' value='1' readonly/>
          </td>
          <td width='15%' id='addinput'>
            <input type='text' size='19' id='item_name0' name='item_name[0]' placeholder='3M EC 2214 Regular Adhesive EpoxySize: 150ml box ' value='3M EC 2214 Regular Adhesive EpoxySize: 150ml box ' />
          </td>
          <td width='5%'>
            <input size='1' class='qty' type='text' name='qty[]' id='qty[]' value='10' readonly/>
          </td>
          <td width='5%'>
            <input size='1' type='text' name='unitprice[0]' value='223.15' readonly/>
          </td>
          <td width='5%'>
            <input size='5' type='text' name='total_old' value='2231.500' readonly/>
          </td>
          <td width='8%'>
            <input size='7' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value='219479.000' />
          </td>
          <input class='txt' type='hidden' size='3' id='addon_value[]' name='addon_value[]' value='0' onchange='calcTotals()'>
          <td width='7%'>
            <input class='total' size='6' type='text' id='add_value[]' name='add_value[]' value='373114'>
          </td>
          <td width='7%'>
            <select id='currency_change[]' name='currency_change[]'>
              <option value=''>select</option>
              <option value=USD data-price=1>USD</option>
              <option value=INR data-price=68.128019>INR</option>
              <option value=GBP data-price=0.692675>GBP</option>
              <option value=EUR data-price=0.895982>EUR</option>
              <option selected="selected" value=SGD data-price=1.400105>SGD</option>
              <option value=AUD data-price=1.3949>AUD</option>
              <option value=CAD data-price=1.377725>CAD</option>
              <option value=CHF data-price=0.986467>CHF</option>
              <option value=JPY data-price=114.6032>JPY</option>
              <option value=MYR data-price=4.136531>MYR</option>
              <option value=ZAR data-price=15.73123>ZAR</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <input type="hidden" class="inrvalue" id="inrvalue" name="inrvalue" value="68.128019">
          <input type="hidden" class="deptip" id="dept-input" />
          <input type="hidden" class="priceip" id="price-input" />
          <input type="hidden" class="cs" id="cs" name="cs" value="SGD">
          <td width="7%">
            <input size="5" type="text" data-value="" name='total1[]' id='total1[]' value="13531.598" readonly class="total1" />
          </td>
          <td width='7%'>
            <input class='price_unit' size='6' type='text' id='price_unit[]' name='price_unit[]' value='1353.160' readonly>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <div align="center" class="base">
          <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tbody id="people">
              <tr class="trToiitrate">
                <td width='6%'>
                  <input size='1' type='hidden' name='id[1]' value='1580' readonly/>
                  <input size='1' type='text' name='sl[1]' value='2' readonly/>
                </td>
                <td width='15%' id='addinput'>
                  <input type='text' size='19' id='item_name1' name='item_name[1]' placeholder='CONAP CE-1170 ACRYLIC CONFORMAL COATING AS PER MIL-1-46058, Type AR,Size: 01 quart = 0.8 kg' value='CONAP CE-1170 ACRYLIC CONFORMAL COATING AS PER MIL-1-46058, Type AR,Size: 01 quart = 0.8 kg'
                  />
                </td>
                <td width='5%'>
                  <input size='1' class='qty' type='text' name='qty[]' id='qty[]' value='2' readonly/>
                </td>
                <td width='5%'>
                  <input size='1' type='text' name='unitprice[1]' value='285' readonly/>
                </td>
                <td width='5%'>
                  <input size='5' type='text' name='total_old' value='570.000' readonly/>
                </td>
                <td width='8%'>
                  <input size='7' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value='27735.800' />
                </td>
                <input class='txt' type='hidden' size='3' id='addon_value[]' name='addon_value[]' value='0' onchange='calcTotals()'>
                <td width='7%'>
                  <input class='total' size='6' type='text' id='add_value[]' name='add_value[]' value='83207.4'>
                </td>
                <td width='7%'>
                  <select id='currency_change[]' name='currency_change[]'>
                    <option value=''>select</option>
                    <option value=USD data-price=1>USD</option>
                    <option value=INR data-price=68.128019>INR</option>
                    <option value=GBP data-price=0.692675>GBP</option>
                    <option value=EUR data-price=0.895982>EUR</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value=SGD data-price=1.400105>SGD</option>
                    <option value=AUD data-price=1.3949>AUD</option>
                    <option value=CAD data-price=1.377725>CAD</option>
                    <option value=CHF data-price=0.986467>CHF</option>
                    <option value=JPY data-price=114.6032>JPY</option>
                    <option value=MYR data-price=4.136531>MYR</option>
                    <option value=ZAR data-price=15.73123>ZAR</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" class="inrvalue" id="inrvalue" name="inrvalue" value="68.128019">
                <input type="hidden" class="deptip" id="dept-input" />
                <input type="hidden" class="priceip" id="price-input" />
                <input type="hidden" class="cs" id="cs" name="cs" value="SGD">
                <td width="7%">
                  <input size="5" type="text" data-value="" name='total1[]' id='total1[]' value="1710.003" readonly class="total1" />
                </td>
                <td width='7%'>
                  <input class='price_unit' size='6' type='text' id='price_unit[]' name='price_unit[]' value='855.001' readonly>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <div align="center" class="base">
```

Comment: I will surely try this. May need your help since iam very new to jquery. anyways let me try and thank you so much for your time

Comment: so after  $(".trToiitrate").each(function(e) { if i add my code of select on change, will it work. i just tried but it was not working

Comment: as per your requirement you need to loop through tr on select so inside select event  you need to iterate over .trToiitrate class and the iterate over td in td iteration you have to write your logic